# Unable to connect to a device on LAN when the router is disconnected from the internet

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, broadband

I have flask server running on my laptop. I can reach it from the same laptop using the static IP address 192.168.1.x at all times but I cannot reach it from my phone (connected to the same router) if there is any issue with my internet connection. I expected it to work anyway since the address that I'm specifying is reserved for local networks. Is there a way to make it work?

My router is: Binatone DT 850W